# Infinite Scrolling doesn't seem to be working (first scroll enter data is loading)

Tags: angularjs, nginfinitescroll

I have a JSON data which contains 1000 products.

I am trying to show those products on my web page as a 3*3 grid using infinite scrolling.

On very first scroll only , entire data is getting loaded.

My code looks like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img{
width : 200px;
height : 200px;
display : inline-block;
margin-right : 5 ;
margin-bottom : 5;
}
</style>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src = "ng-infinite-scroll.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='DemoController'>
<div infinite-scroll="loadMore()" infinite-scroll-distance="0" infinite-scroll-disabled = "false">
  <div  ng-repeat="product in productList" class="col-md-4 panel panel-info">
     <p class = "panel-heading">#{{product.id}}&nbsp;&nbsp;{{product.name}}</p>
    <img ng-src ="{{ product.img }}" alt = "{{ product.img}}"  class="imageStyle">
    <h3> <small>{{product.cat}}</small></h3>
    <p class="text-danger">{{product.price | currency:'&#8377;'}}</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div style='clear: both;'></div>
</div>
<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['infinite-scroll']);
myApp.controller('DemoController', function($scope,$http) {

    $http.get('https://test-prod-api.herokuapp.com/products').then(function(response){
    //console.log(response.data);
    //$scope.images = response.data.products;
    $scope.productList = [];
    for(var i=0;i<9;i++){
    $scope.productList.push(response.data.products[i]);
    }
    console.log($scope.productList.length);
    $scope.loadMore = function() {
  console.log('called' + $scope.productList.length);
    for(var j = $scope.productList.length; j <= $scope.productList.length+9 && $scope.productList.length<1000; j++) {
    console.log("j value  "+j);
     $scope.productList.push(response.data.products[j]);
   }
    console.log('images array length  '+$scope.productList.length);
 };

    });

  //$scope.images = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];



});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please suggest me changes I need to make in above code.

Working example is more appreciable.

Please help me to get this done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On very first scroll only , entire data is getting loaded.

This is due to the wrong loop termination condition:

```
j <= $scope.productList.length+9 && $scope.productList.length < 1000
```

which would cause the loop not to stop until *`j` is less than or equal to `productList.length`* **AND** *`productList.length` is less than `1000`*.

Since after the initialization of the `productList` array, its length turns `9` and `9` is always less than `1000`, you'll end up loading (pushing) all the array items in `response.data.products` upon first call of the `loadMore()` function.

### Solution

Instead, try something like the following (as in the docs for `ngInfiniteScroll`) in your `loadMore()` function:

```
var lastIndex = $scope.productList.length-1;
for (var j = 1; j <= 9; j++) { // load 9 more on every call to the loadMore function
   $scope.productList.push(response.data.products[lastIndex + j]);
}
```

### [***Demo***](https://jsfiddle.net/baktash93/uu6t5cbh/)